# Value passed to function doubling inside call

Tags: c++, function, unspecified-behavior

I'm currently having an issue with a function call of get_set() for a doubly-linked list class I am making. The function returns a vector of all the elements within the list from *position_from* to *position_to*. For the tests I am sending

dll_UT->get_set( dll_UT->size()/2+1 , dll_UT->size()-1)

however, the value of dll_UT->size() somehow doubles within the call. When called directly before in my COUT statement, it shows the correct value of 100, but when inside the function this turns to 200. I've left console logs below as well as screenshots of the test.cpp and doubly_linked_list.cpp.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated as I've never seen this type of behavior before and would like to understand why such a thing is occuring.

````
Doubly_linked_list get_set(unsigned position_from, unsigned_position to){

 std::cout << "\n\t__NEW TEST__\nSize of size/2+1 = " << this->size()/2+1 << "\nSize of size()-1 = " << this->size()-1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "position_from = " << position_from << "\nposition_to = " << position_to << std::endl;
         //value of position_from == 200, should be == this->size()/2+1 which = 100
        

        std::vector<int> temp;
        temp.reserve(position_to - position_from);

        while(position_from < position_to){
            temp.push_back( this->get_data(position_from) );
            position_from++;
        }
        
        temp.push_back(this->get_data(position_to));
      
        std::cout << "Size of position_from = " << position_from << "\nSize of position_to = " << position_to << "\n\t__END TEST__" << std::endl;

        return temp;```
}

Test.cpp {
```std::cout << "\nTEST.cpp::: dll_UT-size() = " << dll_UT->size() << 
    "\nTEST.cpp::: dll_UT-size()/2+1 = " << dll_UT->size()/2+1 << std::endl;
      //assuring dll_UT->size()/2+1 = 100     

    std::cout << "\nTEST.cpp::: expected_set.size() = " << expected_set.size() << 
    "\nTEST.cpp::: expected_set.begin()+expected_set.size()/2+1 = " << expected_set.size()/2+1 << std::endl;

    ASSERT_EQ(std::vector<int> (expected_set.begin()+expected_set.size()/2+1,expected_set.end()), 
                                dll_UT->get_set( dll_UT->size()/2+1 , dll_UT->size()-1));//second half of data
                                //               ^first operand doubled, ^second operand fine
//actually value sent is 200. dll_UT->size() is somehow doubling and equaling 400 but only for first operand of get_set(unsigned, unsigned)
````

[Updated Caputre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LUMO.png)

Comment: `get_set` is defined to take no parameters, but is called with two parameters. The code you show is not the code you are actually compiling. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: "however, the value of `dll_UT->size()` somehow doubles within the call. When called directly before in my COUT statement, it shows the correct value of 100" The very first line  of the output in your picture is `dll_UT->size() == 199`. Where do you see 100, and why do you believe it to be the correct value?

Comment: get set takes two unsigned int values specifically

```get_set(unsigned position_from, unsigned position_to);```

The size of the linked list is 199 after adding elements in a loop, that is why I can confirm the correct value of ```size()/2+1 is 100```. You can also see that this is the correct value by the cout statement which shows the value of this. 

Despite this, when doing the same calculation inside the function call it is doubling.

Comment: Not in the code shown. In your question, you have `Doubly_linked_list get_set(){...}` . It also returns `std::vector<int>` and not a `Doubly_linked_list` (unless you have a typedef that defines the latter as an alias for the former). Again, show the code you are actually compiling, preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I tried to go back and edit the original post but I'm unable to.

Comment: You should be able to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69875071/edit) your question. There's an "Edit" link right underneath.

Comment: If you are asking why `position_from` has different values at the beginning and at the end of the function - well, because you are incrementing it in between. As in `position_from++;`

Comment: I've gone back and edited the posts code and screenshot to more clearly reflect what is happening. As seen in the capture: 

```dll_UT->size()/2+1 = 100```
but when this is passed into get_set(unsigned, unsigned), it's somehow doubling the value, but only for the first operand.

Comment: The comment in the code says `value of position_from == 200`, but that's not true - the screen capture shows `position_from = 99`. What seems to be the problem? Again, if you are asking why `position_from` increases **at the end of the function**, then that's because the function increments it until it becomes equal to `position_to`.

Comment: My issue isn't that it's changing post loop, as that is expected behavior. The screenshot I'd initially uploaded was of the prior test which worked fine. I've re-uploaded the correct screenshot now to show the test where this behavior is shown. As seen in it, the value of ```position_from is = 200```, when it should be equal to 100, the same as ```dll_UT->size()/2+1```

Comment: You'd have to show a [mcve]. The problem is somewhere in the code not shown.